# Problema ao carregar o winbugs no R

Tags: r, windows

Estou tentando rodar um código no R que carrega o pacote `winbugs` que eu já tenho instalado

```
require(R2WinBUGS);
```

mas estou tendo este erro

```
   Read 180 items
    Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(con, "rb") :
      cannot open file 'c:/Program Files/WinBUGS14//System/Rsrc/Registry.odc': No such file or directory
    Error in bugs.run(n.burnin, bugs.directory, WINE = WINE, useWINE = useWINE,  : 
      WinBUGS executable does not exist in c:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/
    Called from: bugs.run(n.burnin, bugs.directory, WINE = WINE, useWINE = useWINE, 
        newWINE = newWINE, WINEPATH = WINEPATH)
```

Já troquei o *working directory*. Estou usando windows 10 e tentei sem sucesso instalar o winbugs.

**EDIT:** Pessoal consegui executar meu código após a instalação do WinBugs14, rodou normal, só que apareceu isso aqui

```
Read 180 items
Error in file(con, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'c:/Program Files/WinBUGS14//System/Rsrc/Registry_Rsave.odc', reason 'Permission denied'
2: In file(con, "wb") :
  cannot open file 'c:/Program Files/WinBUGS14//System/Rsrc/Registry.odc': Permission denied
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SO em Português. Favor traduzir sua pergunta.

Comment: Me parece que o AP não fala português e postou aqui por engano, fornecer uma resposta aqui não o ajudaria em nada. @PRAGAKHAM This is the portuguese version of StackOverflow, if you don't speak portuguese please ask you question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/). And by the way, make sure you have WinBUGS installed on the `c:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/`directory.

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou executar o R como administrador?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]